# Column Group and Count

Tags: sql, grouping

Is it possible to create a query using the following table:

```
    YEAR    MAKE    MODEL
    2012    CHEVY   CAMARO
    2012    CHEVY   CORVETTE
    2013    CHEVY   CORVETTE
    2013    CHEVY   CAMARO
    2013    NISSAN  GT-R
```

that would output a result such as:

```
    CATEGORY    VALUE    TOTAL
    YEAR        2012     2
    YEAR        2013     3
    MAKE        CHEVY    4
    MAKE        NISSAN   1
    MODEL       CAMARO   2
    MODEL       CORVETTE 2
    MODEL       GT-R     1
```

Comment: oops, what database are we talking about here?

Comment: mySQL. I have a filter bar on the side. Instead of calling each category group in a separate query, I thought that I could make one call to the database and get a single result set back. Then I could loop through the results sets and group on the web server side for display purposes. I still have several other categories that are not shown and also will have to apply "WHERE" filters to each category to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'YEAR' AS category, CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)), COUNT(*) AS total FROM YouTable
GROUP BY year
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MAKE' AS category, make, COUNT(*) FROM YouTable
GROUP BY make
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MODEL' AS category, model, COUNT(*) FROM YouTable
GROUP BY model
```

SQL standart query, if your RDBMS IS SQL SERVER version>=2005 OR Oracle version >=10g
you can use PIVOT/UNPIVOT CLAUSE.